# Understanding the concept of $P(u/v)$ in the context of First Order Logic.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Working on the book: Angelo Margaris. "First Order Mathematical Logic" (p. 47)

> Let $u$ and $v$ be variables and $P$ a formula. $P$ admits $u$ for $v$ if and only if every free occurrence of $v$ in $P$ becomes a free occurrence of $u$ in $P(u/v)$.

The author provides this example:

> $P$ is $\exists y(y>x)$. Below we list some terms, and alongside each term the result of substituting this term for $x$ in $P$.

$$
\begin{align*}
2 \quad & \exists y(y>2) & P(2/x)\\
y \quad & \exists y(y>y) & P(y/x)
\end{align*}
$$

In the second case, the first and only free ocurrence of $x$ in $P$ becomes bound in $P(y/x)$.

However, I have two questions:

- In the first case, I cannot see why 2 becomes a free occurrence in P as it is a constant.

The definition of "$P$ admits $u$ for $v$" does not mention anything about bound ocurrences of $v$ becoming free.

- Let $P$ be $\exists y(y > x)$, then $P(x/y)$ would be $\exists y(x > x)$ ? Is this forbidden ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author states some examples of *substitution*: some correct and some not.

The example $[∃y(y>x)](2/x)$ is a correct one because it substitute the *term* $2$ in place of the free variable $x$ causing no harm [see the definition of *substitution*: "Let $P$ a formula, $v$ a variable and $t$ a term. Then $P(t/v)$ is..."]

The second example, instead, is an example of "forbidden" substitution: the formula does **not** admits $y$ for $x$ because if we replace the free occurrence of $x$ with $y$ into the formula $∃y(y>x)$ what we get is $∃y(y>y)$ and the previous free occurrence of $x$ is now a bound occurrence of $y$, and this modifies the meaning of the formula.

---

Regarding $[∃y(y>x)](x/y)$, the result is not $∃y(x>x)$; according to the definition: "... $P(t/v)$ is the formula that results when each free occurrence of $v$ in $P$ is replaced by an occurrence of $t$."

In $∃y(y>x)$ there are **no** free occurrences of $y$; thus $[∃y(y>x)](x/y)$ will be: $∃y(y>x)$.

The substitution operation acts on *free* occurrences.

Comment: Thank you so much for a cristal clear explanation, @Mauro Allegranza ! Just to clarify, I was merely pointing out what happened in the second example. I forgot to add that it was forbidden. But your explanation added clarity. I appreciate it.